Is switching between structs possible by type property?
Let's say I have a struct called Document, and has type property as enum between Article, Book and Paper.
enum DocumentType {
  BookType
  ArticleType
  PaperType
}

struct Book {
  authors: Vec<Author>,
  publication: String,
  rights: Vec<Right>,
  ...
}

struct Article {
  author: Author,
  publication: String,
  link: String,
  ...
}

struct Paper {
  authors: Vec<Author>,
  organization: String,
  chapters: Vec<Chapter>
  ...
}

struct Document {
  id: uint8,
  title: String,
  summary: String
  type: DocumentType,
  // .... rest of what flows from each type  
}

Is this possible to switch between types or extend types in rust?
My opinion is to go for a flat database design, i.e., to store all the fields of a document in one table with validation for each by type.
I might need to have Book, Paper & Article as separate structures models but have Document as a trait.
trait Document<T> {
  fn query(&self) -> T;
}


Side note: do you really want the id to be limited to 256 values?

I don't foresee id to be larger than 64bits, doesn't usize take whatever the processor can handle?

@Krishna u8 is 8 bits, not 8 bytes. It has the range 0-255 (inclusive). You might want u64 instead?

You're absolutely right, I did usize instead of u8, I just gave that for question purposes as an example.. usize should be taking 64 or 32 depending on where it is running, yes?

Enums conceptually are tagged unions, so they can do this.
enum DocumentKind {
    Book(Book),
    Article(Article),
    Paper(Paper),
}

struct Book {
    authors: Vec<Author>,
    publication: String,
    rights: Vec<Right>,
}

struct Article {
    author: Author,
    publication: String,
    link: String,
}

struct Paper {
    authors: Vec<Author>,
    organization: String,
    chapters: Vec<Chapter>,
}

struct Document {
    id: u8,
    title: String,
    summary: String,
    kind: DocumentKind,
}

The Document's kind attribute must contain either a Book, Article, or Paper given this definition.  You can use match to determine which, as well as to access the inner value.  For example:
fn example(doc: &Document) {
    match &doc.kind {
        DocumentKind::Book(book) => {
            // book is a &Book
        }
        DocumentKind::Article(article) => {
            // article is a &Article
        }
        DocumentKind::Paper(paper) => {
            // paper is a &Paper
        }
    }
}


when I'm serializing this, doesn't this look like
{
  "id": 123,
  "title": "something big",
  "summary": "something concise",
  "kind": {}
}


does this is mean, I have to implement my own serializing function for kind ?

@Krishna If you are using serde, you can use #[serde(flatten)] on the Document::kind attribute. Then you need to decide how you want the enum represented. See https://serde.rs/enum-representations.html . You almost certainly want internally tagged or untagged.
